# Fixed left navigation scrolling horizontal

Tags: css

I have a vertical navigation bar to the left with a position set to fixed, if I resize my window and use the horizontal scrollbar content div goes behind and editor overlaps navigation bar.

Image:

[image: Editor overlaps navigation]

Code:

```
/* page.php */

<?php require(ABSPATH . 'header.php'); ?>

some content ...

<?php require(ABSPATH . 'footer.php'); ?>

/* header.php */

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<div id="header">
</div>

<?php require(ABSPATH . 'menu.php'); ?>

<div id="content-wrapper">

/* menu.php */

<div id="left-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-title">
            <a href="#">Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

/* footer.php */

</div><!-- close content wrapper -->

<div id="footer">
***FOOTER***
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* menu */

#left-menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}

/* menu style */

#left-menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#left-menu li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#left-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

#left-menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

/* menu title style */ 

#left-menu ul .menu-title {
    line-height: 45px;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title { 
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title {
    color: #999999;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

/* content | header | footer */

#content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

#header {

}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

How do I avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By having a padding on the left that pushed your content to outside the area of the menu?

Comment: @somethinghere I just replaced `margin-left: 200px;` with `padding-left: 200px;` but no differens, other ideas?

Comment: Could you post some html as well? Also, does your wysiwyg editor have an absolute position? If so, revert to `margin-left` and add `position: relative` to your wrapper to make absolute elements behave inside your content box and not inside your document.

Comment: @somethinghere HTML is now in the post. Wysiwyg editor is between content wrapper div without `position: absolute` I just added `position: relative` as you suggested but I get same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu has a position assigned to it, but the parent div doesn't. So the parent div has no idea where is should be positioned, but the menu wants to be fixed or positioned relative to the parent div.

What you should do is assign the parent div to be the full width of the page at least, and give it a position or float it left or right. This will then mean any div inside there will position itself accordingly.

Comment: The issue then will be with whatever contains the text editor and how that's being positioned.

Comment: Actually, the isdue is that the fixed element didnt have a position set. It works fine when you add `top: 0; left: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in order for any positioning to take actual affect, it needs position values as the defaults are `auto`, not `0`. Try the following:

```
#left-menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; /* <- you need a value! */
    top: 0; /* <- you need a value! */
    /* Also note a float is not necessary for a fixed or absolute element */
    width: 180px;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

Heres a working implementation:

```css
/* menu */

#left-menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}

/* menu style */

#left-menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#left-menu li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#left-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

#left-menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

/* menu title style */ 

#left-menu ul .menu-title {
    line-height: 45px;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title { 
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title {
    color: #999999;
}

#left-menu ul .menu-title a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

/* content | header | footer */

#content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

#header {

}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="content-wrapper">

<div id="left-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-title">
            <a href="#">Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
Heres some content to see it gets pushed
</div><!-- close content wrapper -->

<div id="footer">
***FOOTER***
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but same result. Could it be TinyMCE which is causing the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Is tinymce in your content div? The only way tinymce could make this fail is if it itself uses `position: absolute`, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zysx6q8L/ in my content I have tinymce inside a form if you resize this window horizontal scrollbar will be shown. How could I avoid this?

Comment: Am I debugging your entire site now? Check your styles - your `textarea` has a `width:100%` but your `input` doesn't, so eventually your `input` will be bigger than the screen and create a scrollbar.

Comment: No that's not my intention. In my css file I give my input field a custom width maybe this is causing the problem. I just added `overflow-x: hidden` to content wrapper after this horizontal scrollbar will not be visible and then problem is no longer present.

Comment: Yes, `overflow-x: hidden` hides your horizontal overflow. It, however, does not solve the _cause_ of your problem. Please search for the element that is pushing your size to be wider than your viewport and solve it that way. I cannot say what it is here, but you are just hiding the problem and it will bite you in the ass at a later point.

Comment: I agree with you. But if only text is added to content area there is no problem, then i tried with a input field without any css style after that i minimize my window and horizontal scrollbar is visible. Right now I can not find any solution but I will look forward.